# Updating the MarkerImage sprite origin point in a Google Maps marker (v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I want to dynamically update the "origin" point of a sprite generated by the MarkerImage constructor in Google Maps API v3, and am wondering if that's possible without generating a new MarkerImage entirely.

Here's some code:

```js
// Marker options
var markerOptions = {
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/content/marker.png', 
      new google.maps.Size(88,88),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(44,88)
    ),
  position: position,
  map: map
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
```

Can I do something along the lines of marker.setPoint(0,10) or do I need to create a new MarkerImage just to set the sprite origin again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way (at least according to the API reference) to alter the properties of a MarkerImage after it has been created.  You can create a new MarkerImage and call `marker.setIcon()`.

Answer (score 4):

When the MarkerImage is draw on the map the quickest way to do that is :

```js
marker.getIcon().origin = new google.maps.Point(0, 10);
marker.setIcon(marker.getIcon()); //re-draw the MarkerIcon
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the origin property of the marker's icon. In your example:

```js
marker.getIcon().origin = new google.maps.Point(0, 10);
```

The following also works:

```js
marker.icon.origin = new google.maps.Point(0, 10);
```

Comment: Upvoted because you're right—technically I can set the origin property with both of those methods, however it seems that it does not affect the previously-set MarkerImage.  If I inspect the object, I can see that the origin property is updated, but there is no change reflected in the MarkerImage onscreen.